# Unable to get "complete" list of pages user is admin of from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have the user access token and I'm making a call to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=

This gets me the list of pages for the user like:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {<page data}, 
{<page2data>}
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "<>",
      "after": "<>"
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose the user added another page on Facebook after half an hour. I try to get the new page list using the same call but I only get the initial list of X pages and not the one extra page that the user has added.
I'm using a Permanent Access Token, is that the issue here?

Also, currently I have 23 pages for the user and the pagination cursors before/after which I'm tryna use to get the next list of pages. I get a data [] blank when I do so.

Comment: I read in a different question yesterday, that the page the user was added to as an admin after the token was created did not show up, it only did after they removed `manage_pages` permission and then granted it again. Not sure whether this is a new security feature, or simply a bug.

Comment: Ah. Damn. That might be the case.

Comment: This answer may help you:- [Facebook API me/accounts returns not all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the token is a page access token for a user with a role on the page (other than ***live contributor***) and that it have these permissions assigned:

- `manage_pages`
- `pages_show_list`

Also, when pagination is present there is always a `next` attribute (inside the `paging` object) which is an URL that contains the page cursor, access token, and other URL parameters. If it is not present, it's because you are on the last page. You can verify that by using the `limit` field, for example: `/me/accounts/?limit=5`

You can read about that here:

- [User pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/)
- [Pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging)

Comment: how can one have a page access token in the first place if he doesn't even have any info about the pages? There will be no page_id available then how can we get the page access token?